# Running SLAM without encoders

Tags: slam, mapping, wheeled-robot, sensor-fusion, encoders

I am new to the concept of SLAM and mapping, however I ordered a robot vehicle platform which I bought [here](https://www.waveshare.com/wave-rover.htm) so that I can explore and practice it on the platform. I also got a 2d liDAR, depth camera and a Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB RAM)

In checking the wiki on the vehicle (linked [here](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/WAVE_ROVER), I found that although it comes with an onboard IMU, it does not come with motor encoders.

I wanted to ask whether this would prevent me or limit my ability to implement SLAM or if it is still feasible to execute it.

If so? what should be my approach to implementing SLAM to such a vehicle (since I am a beginner to SLAM)?